# Potentials in Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, potential-theory

Could someone give an intuitive interpretation of potentials in the field of probability theory. How do they link to the theory of stochastic processes. And maybe link this with SEP. References are appreciated as well. Thank you very much.